# sqlalchemy event listen load does not work with pytest fixture

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pytest, fastapi

First of all, I am not good at English. Please understand

Problem solved, but no cause found.

Problem is, if you return a sprit instance stored in db from fixure to create_sprit, the load event listener does not work in the logic of the test function that uses that sprit instance

I wonder why this problem occurs

event.listen(): load "*" -> " " / upsert " " -> "*"

---

| package | version |
| --- | --- |
| fastapi | 0.105.0 |
| pytest | 8.0.0 |
| sqlalchemy | 2.0.23 |

**Models & Event**

```py
class Spirit(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'spirit'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(Enum(SpiritType), nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(length=50), nullable=True)
    name_ko = Column(String(length=50), nullable=True)
    unit = Column(Enum(Unit), nullable=False)
    amount = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    cocktail_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('cocktail.id'))
    # cocktail = relationship("Cocktail", backref="spirits")


class Material(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'material'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(Enum(MaterialType), nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(length=50), nullable=False)
    name_ko = Column(String(length=50), nullable=False)
    unit = Column(Enum(Unit), nullable=False)
    amount = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    cocktail_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('cocktail.id'), nullable=True)
    # cocktail = relationship("Cocktail", backref="materials")


class Cocktail(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cocktail'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(length=50), nullable=False)
    name_ko = Column(String(length=50), nullable=False)
    abv = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    skill = Column(Enum(Skill), nullable=False)
    usage_count = Column(Integer, default=0)

    spirits = relationship("Spirit", cascade="all, delete", backref="cocktail")
    materials = relationship("Material", cascade="all, delete", backref="cocktail")


# define: Event Listener function
def serdes_columns(target, action):
    print(f"serdes_columns: {action}")
    for column in class_mapper(target.__class__).columns:
        if column.key in ['name', 'name_ko']:
            value = getattr(target, column.key)
            if value is not None:
                modified_value = value.replace(" ", "_") if action == 'serialize' else value.replace("_", " ")
                setattr(target, column.key, modified_value)
                print(f"{action} {column.key}: {value} -> {modified_value}")


def after_select_listener(target, connection, **kwargs):
    serdes_columns(target, 'deserialize')


def before_insert_listener(mapper, connection, target):
    serdes_columns(target, 'serialize')


def before_update_listener(mapper, connection, target):
    serdes_columns(target, 'serialize')


for model in [Spirit, Material, Cocktail]:
    event.listen(model, 'load', after_select_listener)
    event.listen(model, 'before_insert', before_insert_listener)
    event.listen(model, 'before_update', before_update_listener)
```

**conftest**

```py
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)
TestSessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine, class_=TestSession)


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def init_db():
    Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
    yield
    # Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def db(init_db):
    session = TestSessionLocal()
    try:
        yield session
    finally:
        session.rollback()
        session.close()


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def client(db):
    app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = lambda: db
    with TestClient(app) as _client:
        yield _client


@pytest.fixture
def spirit(db):
    spirit_data = {
        "type": SpiritType.Whisky,
        "name": "Test Spirit",
        "name_ko": "테스트 기주",
        "unit": Unit.ml,
        "amount": 50,
        "cocktail_id": None
    }

    # ** sqlalchemy event listen load not working **
    _spirit = spirit_crud.create_spirit(db, spirit_schema.SpiritCreate(**spirit_data))
    return _spirit

    # ** but, this is work **
    # return _spirit.id
    # return spirit_schema.SpiritCreate(**spirit_data)
```

**Test**

```py
def test_spirit_detail(client, spirit):
    response = client.get("/api/spirits/1")
    print(response.json())
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

**result**

log, event listen load not work

```
------------------------------- live log setup --------------------------------
DEBUG    2024-02-27 17:44:20 asyncio::proactor_events.py:__init__:633: Using proactor: IocpProactor
serdes_columns: serialize
serialize name: Test Spirit -> Test_Spirit
serialize name_ko: 테스트 기주 -> 테스트_기주
-------------------------------- live log call --------------------------------
INFO     2024-02-27 17:44:20 httpx::_client.py:_send_single_request:1027: HTTP Request: GET http://testserver/api/spirits/1 "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
PASSED                                                                   [100%]
{'type': 'Whisky', 'name': 'Test_Spirit', 'name_ko': '테스트_기주', 'unit': 'ml', 'amount': 50, 'id': 1, 'cocktail_id': None}
```

log, event listen load is work

```
------------------------------- live log setup --------------------------------
DEBUG    2024-02-27 17:47:30 asyncio::proactor_events.py:__init__:633: Using proactor: IocpProactor
serdes_columns: serialize
serialize name: Test Spirit -> Test_Spirit
serialize name_ko: 테스트 기주 -> 테스트_기주
-------------------------------- live log call --------------------------------
INFO     2024-02-27 17:47:30 httpx::_client.py:_send_single_request:1027: HTTP Request: GET http://testserver/api/spirits/1 "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
PASSED                                                                   [100%]
serdes_columns: deserialize
deserialize name: Test_Spirit -> Test Spirit
deserialize name_ko: 테스트_기주 -> 테스트 기주
{'type': 'Whisky', 'name': 'Test Spirit', 'name_ko': '테스트 기주', 'unit': 'ml', 'amount': 50, 'id': 1, 'cocktail_id': None}
```

---

If the return value is any value or object other than an instance created by fixture, no problem occurs.
And if you don't use that fixture, the problem won't happen.

[sqlalchemy](/questions/tagged/sqlalchemy) [pytest](/questions/tagged/pytest) [fastapi](/questions/tagged/fastapi) [python](/questions/tagged/python)

Comment: Since you're creating a TestSession with `autoflush=False` - your session will never be written to the database unless you explicitly flush it yourself. And since the `before_` events are triggered when the SQL is emitted to the database, that never happens since there is never any SQL emitted - since the session doesn't get flushed. You can either flush it yourself after the yield to have the SQL emitted, or probably just leave autoflush on - since you're rolling back the transaction regardless. And your English is more than good enough. Thank you for the effort.

Comment: @MatsLindh

It wasn't directly related to what you said, but thanks to you, I was able to find the problem.
1. The two fixtures were sharing the same DB session.
2. It was not erased from memory while returning instances created in fixture, and continued to exist in identity maps during the test function.
3. So the event listen load was not working.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great that you found the problem! Add it as an answer and accept your own answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**cause**

1. The two fixtures were sharing the same DB session.
2. It was not erased from memory while returning instances created in fixture, and continued to exist in identity maps during the test function.
3. So the event listen load was not working.

**Solution plan**

1. Use different DB sessions in two fixtures
2. Returns object values other than the created instance